# PySpark: Regex Replace Group

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to join two tables based on a common ID, but there's a mismatch in dates across these files which I'm trying to normalise.

Given this data:

```
+-------+-------------------+----------------------------+
|dataset|id                 |topic                       |
+-------+-------------------+----------------------------+
|2020A  |1128290566331031552|papuaNewguineaEarthquake2019|
|2020A  |1128293303659716608|papuaNewguineaEarthquake2019|
|2020A  |1152200235847966726|athensEarthquake2019        |
|2020A  |1152204892083281920|athensEarthquake2019        |
|2020A  |1152220394008522753|athensEarthquake2019        |
+-------+-------------------+----------------------------+
```

How would I, for example, replace the `2019` in `papuaNewguineaEarthquake2019` with the first four numbers of the value in the `dataset` column so that:

`papuaNewguineaEarthquake2019` becomes `papuaNewguineaEarthquake2020`?

In other words, how do I use regex to replace a subgroup in one column with a subgroup in another column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `expr` function.

I'm using `regexp_extract` to extract the first 4 digits from the `dataset` column and `regexp_replace` to replace the last 4 digits of the `topic` column with the output of `regexp_extract`.

Regex for first 4 digits: `(^[0-9]{4})`
Regex for last 4 digits: `([0-9]{4}$)`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn("dataset_year",expr("regexp_extract(dataset, '(^[0-9]{4})')"))\
    .withColumn("topic",expr("regexp_replace(topic, '([0-9]{4}$)'\
    , dataset_year)")).drop('dataset_year').show(truncate=False)

+-------+-------------------+----------------------------+
|dataset|id                 |topic                       |
+-------+-------------------+----------------------------+
|2020A  |1128290566331031552|papuaNewguineaEarthquake2020|
|2020A  |1128293303659716608|papuaNewguineaEarthquake2020|
|2020A  |1152200235847966726|athensEarthquake2020        |
|2020A  |1152204892083281920|athensEarthquake2020        |
|2020A  |1152220394008522753|athensEarthquake2020        |
+-------+-------------------+----------------------------+
```